# Give overlay div a height of the full page, not just 100% the screen viewport

Tags: html, css, overlay

i am making a one page style website so each section is set to 100% height.

The issue is, i am using an overlay at some points and i want the overlay to be over the whole height of the website. Not just the 100% viewport height but over the whole site height.

Heres a basic fiddle showing:

http://jsfiddle.net/5KFVx/1/

And some back up code from the fiddle:

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="onepagediv"></div>
<div id="onepagediv"></div>
<div id="onepagediv"></div>

body, html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

#onepagediv {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #f00;
}

#overlay {
background-color: #000;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `#overlay { position: fixed; }` ? It won't stretch the overlay across the whole contents, but it will stick it to the viewport.

Comment: @AndersG dammit haha. I have done the same before and coudldn't remember how. Fixed will do the job! Thanks!

Comment: On a side note, you should make `onepagediv` a class. You're not supposed give the same ID to multiple elements

Comment: Was just for the fiddle, but none the less, lazy on my part!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$('#overlay').height($(document).height());
```

it sets the height of your div to the height of the document.

I also updated your fiddle so you can see it in action.

Comment: Importing jQuery is a little overkill for something this small